# jQuery animation not playing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I thought this code I had would work, but it only works 50%. It works when animating the width  from 0 to 200px, but vice versa it doesn't work.

this works:`$('#left').animate({"width": "200px"}, "1000").show();`

but this doesn't:`$('#left').animate({"width": "0px"}, "1000").hide();`

what am I doing wrong?

[Here is a JSFIDDLE with all the code](http://jsfiddle.net/nV5Tu/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Hide it after the animation completes:

```
$('#left').animate({"width": "0px"}, "1000", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The reason being is that animate fires asynchronously and then hide is immediately called, causing it to just disappear.  Putting it in the complete callback gives you the desired effect.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nV5Tu/12/

Comment: ah, almost there! I probably have to change the show animation too right? first show and then play the animation? because it's not working 100% now when you click on some buttons after each other. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nV5Tu/11/)

Comment: No.  Try using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before all of your animations.  The `show` actually should be like that, so it shows as soon as the animation is starting.